# Type intersections using any

Tags: typescript, intersection, any, inference

From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622:

> Supertype collapsing: A & B is equivalent to A if B is a supertype of A.

However:

```
type a = string & any; // Resolves to any, not string!?
```

This intersection resolves to any. Isn't 'any' a supertype of string? So shouldn't this intersection be just string, due to supertype collapsing? What am I missing?

The use case here is something like:

```
type PropertyMap = {
    prop1: {
        name: "somename";
        required: any;
    };
    prop2: {
        name: "someothername";
        required: never;
    }
}

type RequiredOnly = {
    [P in keyof PropertyMap]: PropertyMap[P] & PropertyMap[P]["required"]
}

// RequiredOnly["prop2"] correctly inferred to be never, but we've
// lost the type info on prop1, since it is now an any (but should
// have been narrowed to it's original type).
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Upvoting for the pun

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In TypeScript, `any` is an escape hatch from the type system.  Or maybe a black hole that eats up every other type it touches.  It is treated both as a top type (any value can be assigned to a variable of type `any`) and a bottom type (a value of type `any` can be assigned to a variable of any type). You might even say it is both a supertype of `string` *and* a subtype of `string`.  That's generally unsound; all types become assignable to all other types if you use `any`, but it's a useful way to opt out of the type system and make assignments that the compiler would otherwise prevent.

If you want a real top type which isn't a black hole, use `unknown`.  You already know that `never` is the real bottom type.  For more interesting reading on this, see [Microsoft/TypeScript#9999](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999).

For your code, try:

```
type PropertyMap = {
    prop1: {
        name: "somename";
        required: unknown; // top type
    };
    prop2: {
        name: "someothername";
        required: never; // bottom type
    }
}

type RequiredOnly = {
    [P in keyof PropertyMap]: PropertyMap[P] & PropertyMap[P]["required"]
}
```

Now `RequiredOnly["prop1"]` should act like what you want.

> <sup>**Any** help appreciated.</sup>

<sup>I see what you did there.</sup>