# Intersection with `any` type

Tags: typescript, intersection

[EDIT] This question is indeed duplicate; see @jcalz's answer on the linked post :)

Related discussion on TS github: [Allowing narrow from any](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999)

---

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20AType%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20any%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20a%3A%20AType%0D%0Aa.a)

When I do `{ a: any } & { a: number }`, TypeScript resolves it to `{ a: any }`. However, considering the meaning of intersection type, I think it should be `{ a: number }`, as only values in `number` type are actually in the intersection of those two types. So I'm not sure about the rationale behind this behavior - maybe it's because `any` is treated specially?

Comment: @jcalz you're right; typescript calls it so. Logically (set-theory), it just seems the opposite.

Comment: @MeirionHughes since you deleted your previous comments, I deleted mine as well so it didn't look like I was a crazy person who talks to himself (which I am, but I don't like it to look that way).   In any case the creators of TypeScript are well-versed in set theory/type theory/logic so I think you are confused about what makes a union and intersection.  Quite possibly you're thinking of property keys, which are [contravariant with their types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12625#issuecomment-264642613).

Comment: yeah sorry, don't want to swamp a question with unrelated comments, so I generally end up deleting them after a while. I think this 'confusion' merits a question. I'll cc you so you can answer if you want.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah it seems like your answer is what I was looking for. I searched for quite a time, assuming someone has already asked the question, but somehow couldn't find the it. Thanks for the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Type intersection

When you intersect two types using `T1 & T2`, the resulting type has of all the properties in `T1`, as well as all of those in `T2`.

If you change your example slightly, to use `string` instead of `any`:

```
type AType = { a: string } & { a: number }

declare const a: AType
a.a // type: string & number
```

we see that `a.a` has the combination of the properties of string and number.

In your example, you might expect it to say that `a.a` was of type `any & number`, but that's just the same as `any`.

#### Type intersection with `any`

When a type (e.g. `number`) is intersected with `any`, `any` behaves as a *subtype* (a narrower type, with all the properties of `number` plus some more). You could say that `any` extends `number`. This leads us to the same behaviour as we see below:

```
type T1 = { a: number, b: number }
type T2 = { a: number }

type Intersection = T1 & T2 // T1 is a subtype of T2, so we get T1
```

Admittedly, this is unintuitive from the perspective that we expect `any` to be a wider (more permissive) type, rather than a narrower one. It is a special case.

You would see your expected behaviour if you used `{}` (the most permissive type) rather than `any`, because `{}` adds no properties to `number`.

Comment: It doesn't look like this answers the question as asked, which is something like "Why is `any & number` treated as `any` instead of `number`?"  You've just asserted that it is, but said nothing about why.

Comment: @jcalz I see what you mean! What do you think now?

Comment: This is better, although a subtype with more properties is considered *narrower*, not *wider*.  That is, every object of type `{foo: string, bar: number}` is a valid object of type `{foo: string}`, but not vice-versa.  So the type with more properties is more restrictive... narrower.  And `any` is intentionally unsound... it behaves as both a subtype and supertype of everything else, so `number | any` is `number & any` is `any`... no other type works that way.

Comment: Yeah, I've corrected to "narrower" but I think that the rest is valid. I guess really, the answer boils down to "because that's how the language was designed".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you said, "because that's how the language was designed", that is. Too bad in this case I'm trying to override a library author's `any` so I guess there aren't much I can do about it haha

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `any` at first place which is supertype of number, what you using is type checking of any and number, so means it can be anything, which means it's `any`!

So any override the number type as it's supertype of number...

In **typescript**, always use specific type, if not sure about the type, use `any`...

So putting check for `any` is exactly like not putting any type check at all...

This is exact words from typescript team for `any`...

> #### Any
>
> We may need to describe the type of variables that we do
>   not know when we are writing an application. These values may come
>   from dynamic content, e.g. from the user or a 3rd party library. In
>   these cases, we want to opt-out of type-checking and let the values
>   pass through compile-time checks. To do so, we label these with the
>   any type:

```
let notSure: any = 4;
notSure = "maybe a string instead";
notSure = false; // okay, definitely a boolean
```

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript,
>   allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during
>   compilation. You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it
>   does in other languages. But variables of type Object only allow you
>   to assign any value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on
>   them, even ones that actually exist:

```
let notSure: any = 4;
notSure.ifItExists(); // okay, ifItExists might exist at runtime
notSure.toFixed(); // okay, toFixed exists (but the compiler doesn't check)

let prettySure: Object = 4;
prettySure.toFixed(); // Error: Property 'toFixed' doesn't exist on type 'Object'
```

> The any type is also handy if you know some part of the type, but
>   perhaps not all of it. For example, you may have an array but the
>   array has a mix of different types:

```
let list: any[] = [1, true, "free"];

list[1] = 100;
```

Comment: This answer isn't exactly right.  You say that `any` is broader than `number`, so `any & number` is the same as `any`.  But `number | string` is broader than number, while `(number | string) & number` is just `number`.  In fact, the issue is that `any` is intentionally unsound and treated as both a supertype *and* a subtype of every other type.  For more info see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46673732/2887218) to a previous question on this topic.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean in simple words, but may not convey it exactly, I'll reword it, tnx @jcalz