# Typescript: Is there a way to ensure type structure when combining with any?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to ensure type structure when combining with any?

Here is an example what I have in mind:

```
function foo<T extends object>(obj: T): { type: 'FooBar' } & T {
    return { type: 'FooBar', ...obj };
}

const bar = foo({bar: 'foo'} as any); // expecting bar type to be {type: 'FooBar'; [x: string]: any;} not any
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdE4AjAK22gD4AKSqgLkQwEo2BvRKATwAO2NgHIAYqgBCAQwBOoxAF9EAMnaJuAKES7Ec7FBBykvAcLGS4shQBpEAOifNlAbi1KtWiAhJREFPKIALzIqAzcgXJiKHCiKjJkMmD8HK6IAPQZOLjC0DBgAOYBQebYfHAB5dxlltLyoukA2rhsfnIFhQC6bMn8ripgcP59WkA)

Comment: No, that's the point of `any`; it is considered compatible with any type whatsoever. Don't use `any` if you want type safety.  Can you elaborate on why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type intersections using any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673558/type-intersections-using-any/46673732#46673732)