# Object type is not recognized sometimes

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following TypeScript code in VS Code:

```
const f1 = ():string => { return "abc"; }

const d:any = {}
d.f2 = ():string => { return "abc"; }
```

Putting the mouse over `f1`, it says `const f1: () => string`.

Putting the mouse over `f2`, it says `any`.

Shouldn't `f2` also be a function that returns a string?

Comment: In *neither* case is the return type of the function a function; the return type of `f1` is a *string*. But the type of *any* prop on something typed `any` will also be `any` - that's what `any` *means*.

Comment: The title should be edited since we're not taking about *return* types.  Maybe "Compiler forgets type after assignment?" or something?  The issue here is a combination of "assignments to variables annotated with a non-union type do not narrow the type of the variable" and "`any` is infectious"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a non-union type `Foo` like this:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
}
```

and if you *annotate* a variable as that type:

```
let foo: Foo = { a: "hello" };
```

then any subsequent assignments or property changes will *not* affect the apparent type of that variable.  For example:

```
let bar = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" };
bar.b; // okay
foo = bar; // okay, bar is assignable to Foo
foo.b // <-- error! Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Foo'
```

Here we have a value, `bar`, known to have a `b` property.  We can assign `bar` to `foo` because `bar` is a valid `Foo` (it has an `a` property).  But once we do that assignment, the compiler has not changed the apparent type of `foo`.  It's still just `Foo`, and therefore we can no longer read a `b` property from it.

Note: for union types, it's more complicated because [control flow analysis (microsoft/TypeScript#8010)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) causes some assignments to apparently narrow the variable's type to some subset of the union members.  But according to [a comment in microsoft/TypeScript#8513](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513#issuecomment-217871478), they haven't done this for non-union types.

---

You annotated `d` as [type `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any), which is a non-union type.  After that, any properties you assign will be immediately forgotten.

Furthermore, the `any` type is an escape hatch from the type system (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46673732/2887218)).  It is infectious and propagates outward to a lot of other types it touches:  `any | Foo` is `any`; `any & Foo` is `any`;  `any["somePropKey"]` is `any`.  The last one, where you [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) a property and get `any` is what happened to `d.f2`.  It's just `any`.

---

If you don't want this to happen, you should stay away from `any` and instead use stronger types, preferably more immutable objects, and let the compiler infer instead of manually annotate where possible:

```
const d2 = {
  f2: () => { return "abc" }
}
d2.f2().toUpperCase(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1):

No, because the object holding it has type `any`, so Typescript cannot infer it will always be a function. The intention of `any` is not throwing type checking errors. If it infers the function type in this case, it would also block you from assigning a value with a different type, which might be undesired.

> When a value is of type any, you can access any properties of it (which will in turn be of type any)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any